# How to match a document with the value of an object attribute in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to match some document in mongoDB:

My Document model :

```
profile: {
  languages: [
    {"name": "French", "level": 1},
    {"name": "English", "level": 2},
    {"name": "Spanish", "level": 4}
  ]
}
```

What I (can) have to search my result set:

```
lang = ["French", "English"];
objLang = [
  {name: "French"},
  {name: "English"}
];
```

What I need is to db.find() all documents that match at least one of the languages, for example :

```
profile.languages.name = "French"
```

or

```
profile.languages.name = "English"
```

WHat I mean is that if I have French or English in my option set, I need to get all the users who have a element of their languages array where name match one of my options, no matter the level of the languages.

So, unless I'm wrong, I can't do

```
db.find({"profile.languages": {$in: [{name: "French"}, {name: "English"}]});
```

How would you proceed ?

Thanks a lot.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you were almost right:

```js
db.collection.find({"profile.languages.name":{$in: ["French","English"]} })
```

Since `profile.languages` is an array of subdocuments, you can call in for one of the subdocument's keys and the subsequent query gets mapped to all subdocuments containing that key.

However, without proper indexing, an added `.explain()` shows something pretty ugly:

```js
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.languages",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "profile.languages.name" : {
            "$in" : [
                "English",
                "French"
            ]
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "profile.languages.name" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "English",
                    "French"
                ]
            }
        },
        "direction" : "forward"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  }
}
```

(`serverInfo`was ommited).

So in order to make this query efficient, you need to create an index over the field you want to query:

```js
db.languages.ensureIndex({"profile.languages.name":1})
```

An added explain now tells us that the matching documents are identified via the index:

```js
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.languages",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "profile.languages.name" : {
            "$in" : [
                "English",
                "French"
            ]
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "profile.languages.name" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "profile.languages.name_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "profile.languages.name" : [
                    "[\"English\", \"English\"]",
                    "[\"French\", \"French\"]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Markus, It will be very usefull in my project / app :)


I didn't know the .explain(), and haven't worked with indexes other than the primary _id, I'm rather an SQL dev by experience ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access both the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document:

```
db.find({
    "profile.languages.name": {
        "$in": ["French", "English"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, since you want `db.find()` to find all documents that match at least one of the languages, that should work. Give that a go and let me know how that pans out.

Comment: @DavidPanart See my answer ;)

Comment: Wow, that works :D

Really, I wasn't expecting it to works. You don't know how many lines of code and perf and exec time you are sparing me, though the solution is so simple I didn't thought It would be appropriate :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query :

Solution 1 :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {
       $unwind:"$profile.languages"
     },
     {
       $match:{"profile.languages.name":{"$in":["French", "English"]}}
     },
     {
       $group:{_id: "$_id", profile:{"$push":"$profile.languages"}}
     }
  ])
```

Solution 2 :

```
db.collection.find(
   {
     "profile.languages.name": 
       {
        "$in": [ "English", "French"]
       }
   }
 );
```